# ExportOptionsSVG class in Illustrator ExtendScript has no "responsive" property

Tags: javascript, svg, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

"responsive" must be a new option for SVG export in Adobe Illustrator. I am using v18.0.0. There is an option on the UI when exporting SVG, but when exporting in ExtendScript there is no way to programatically disable responsiveness.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, lots of Illustrator's UI functionality is not exposed to its own scripting engine. It has been the bane of many a scripter, for years on end now. Only thing I can think of is using an external ("real") SVG editor to fine-tune.

Comment: Adobe makes a damn good creative suite but ExtendScript and the associated toolkit feel like it was developed by a summer intern and then never looked at again lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go ahead and close this question.

The short answer - there is no way to programatically disable responsiveness in Illustrator ExtendScript unfortunately. My main reason for needing it disabled is that responsiveness prevents the width and height attributes from being included in the  tag, and I needed those for my script.

However, as a hack I used the viewBox dimensions which are still retained in the  element as widths and heights. After talking to someone on the design team, they said this is a fine thing to do as the viewBox is representative of what the widths and heights would be.

Answer (score 2):

We found a way to sort of do this with an ExtendScript.

If you open Illustrator and save out a SVG and un-check the option it will stay that way until Illustrator is restarted.  By doing that we were then able to run our script and not have the responsive box checked.